# Can the proof about direct sum decomposition of the inner product space be generalize to infinitely dimension space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

There is a theorem about the finite-dimensional inner product space.

> Suppose a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ with a subspace $W$, then $V=W\bigoplus W^{\bot}$.

And the proof is as follows:
Suppose an orthonormal basis of $W$ is $u_i, \cdots, u_m$, then for $\alpha \in V$:
$$(\alpha-\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_iu_i,\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_ju_j)=0.$$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow(\alpha-\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_iu_i,u_j)=0, j=1,2,\cdots, m.$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a_i=(\alpha,u_i).$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \alpha-\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\alpha,u_i)u_i\in W^{\bot}$$
And since every nonzero vector in $W^{\bot}$ is indenpendent with the vector in $W$. So the above decomposition is direct sum decomposition.

But I am confused if this proof itself can be generalized to the infinete-dimensional inner product space. Actually, I was always confused what properties can be generalized into infinite-dimensional space throughout the linear algebra learning. Can you give me some direct or give some reference that about that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An infinite dimensional inner product space with an inner product (and the additional property of [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)) is called a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space).  It turns out that in a Hilbert space, your statement does not necessarily hold true. In particular a subspace $W$ of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ will satisfy $\mathcal H = W \oplus W^\perp$ if and only if $W$ is [(topologically) closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set).

For example, we necessarily have $\mathcal H = W \oplus W^\perp$ when $W$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$. To be more specific about where the direct generalization of your proof fails, a subspace $W$ that fails to be closed does not have a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).

The study of infinite dimensional vector spaces like this one falls under the domain of [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis).  If you are interested in a relevant reference, you might want to try reading Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*, which I find to be "beginner friendly" (yet fairly comprehensive) relative to similar texts.